# How do I replace an XML node value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, replace, xml-parsing

I have an xml value in sql field

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>D</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>1,2,3,4,5</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>A</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>6,7</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>B</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>8,9,10</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>C</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>11,12,133</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I want to replace the current value of the `MENU_Write` node sibling to the `MENU_ID` node value "`C`", with a blank value. How do I do that?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using SQL Server's [replace value of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx), for example :

```
declare @T XML = '<Menu>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>D</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>1,2,3,4,5</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>A</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>6,7</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>B</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>8,9,10</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>C</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>11,12,133</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>'

set @T.modify('replace value of (//MenuItem[MENU_ID="C"]/MENU_Write/text())[1] with ""')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4859)**

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just use a simple `UPDATE` with the full text you want:

```
UPDATE table
SET xamlfield = 
'<Menu>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>D</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>1,2,3,4,5</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>A</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>6,7</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID>B</MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>8,9,10</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <MENU_ID> </MENU_ID>
    <MENU_Read>1</MENU_Read>
    <MENU_Write>11,12,133</MENU_Write>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>'
WHERE id = 123
```